# How do I make HTML pre and code blocks editable?

Tags: html

I wanted to use the highlight.js project (not really relevant) to make a text editor with syntax highlighting. On it's documentation, it says it automatically highlights all  blocks. I wanted to know if it was possible to make a HTML  block editable.

Comment: Try the `contentEditable`-attribute! All you need to do is to add the attribute and set the value to `true`: `<pre contentEditable="true"></pre>`

Comment: You too @HereticMonkey

Comment: huh? The answers to the posted question answer your question, with the exact same attribute as the answer you accepted. Not sure what "You too" is supposed to mean.

Comment: Oh my previous comment didn't send, I was trying to say thanks to @tacoshy as well as you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HTML [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) attribute.

The attribute can take either `true` or `false` as its value.

Here is an example:

```css
code {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <code contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">Write code here!</code>
</pre>
```

I also used the [`spellcheck`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/spellcheck) attribute to disable spell checking.

You can use the [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) style to disable the outline around the `code` tag.

Example:

```css
pre > code {
  outline: none;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <code contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">Write code here!</code>
</pre>
```